# Он играл в хоккей. Отдельный член предложения или часть сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, словосочетания, члены-предложения

Он играл в хоккей.

В хоккей - часть сказуемого в цельном словосочетании или другая часть речи? Какой здесь тип связи?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, "в хоккей" — дополнение (винительный падеж — отвечает на вопрос "во что?").

Comment: М-м... Подправила и поддержала Ваш ***первый*** ответ — и на вопрос, и на форуме вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Играть в хоккей, играть в футбол, играть в казаки-разбойники, игра в хоккей - это свободные сочетания.

Он (что делал?) играл (во что?) в хоккей. В хоккей - дополнение.

В сочетании ***играл в хоккей*** связь управление, потому что глагол управляет винительным падежом с предлогом **в**.

Answer (score 1):

**Отдельный член предложения или часть сказуемого?** Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, достаточно прочитать словарную статью для глагола «играть»:

**ИГРАТЬ** 2.  (во что, на чём). Проводить время в игре (2 зн.). **И. в футбол.** И. на бильярде. И. в лото, в карты на деньги. И. в загадки (также: говорить обиняками, намёками). И. в прятки.

Таким образом,  мы видим, что существительное «в хоккей» **не входит в состав сказуемого,** а является дополнением в сочетании «играть в хоккей». Это не цельное словосочетание, а свободное: ***играть в хоккей, в футбол***.

Связь – предложное управление винительным падежом,  другие виды подчинительной связи (согласование и примыкание)  явно не походят.